# Ensure that a class derived from a template has a member function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class `Config<typename T, typename... U>`.
Now I want to make sure that all derived classes have a function `void update(const T &t, U...);`

I tried to do this using a virtual function, but this doesn't work, because the `T` is part of the signature. So have can I force an implementation to provide that function?

Comment: Why do you want to make sure of that? What would break if a class doesn't have such a function? How do you plan to call that function? Is `Config` using CRTP, taking the derived class as a template argument? Could you show an example of expected usage; in other words, a [mcve]?

Comment: There are many ways to check whether [a specific member function exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function), you can then use static assert to verify this.

Comment: Really, please confirm that you meant this code does not compile `virtual void update(const T &t, U...) = 0;` ???

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, after thinking more about the class design, I realized that this is indeed not necessary. I wanted to have a kind of compile time check that I don't forget to implement it, but I realized, that if the function is never called, then it's maybe not needed, or the problem is not calling it, and if it is calledthen I get an error anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PiotrNycz points out, a virtual function in the base class should work as follows:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename ...U>
class Config
{
  virtual void update(const T &t, U...) = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename ...U>
struct UnfinishedConfig : Config<T,U...>{

};

template <typename T, typename ...U>
struct FinishedConfig : Config<T,U...>{
  void update(const T &t, U...)override{}
};


int main()
{
   FinishedConfig<int,int> c1;
#if (1)
   UnfinishedConfig<int,int> c2;  // Error!
#endif
}
```

Comment: This works. Strange, because when I tried to use the `override` keyword I got some compiler error earlier. Now this works, so maybe I did something wrong before and haven't realized it.

Comment: @Devolus - Good point about ```override```  specifier - added .